# How to build a complex, hierarchic immutable data structure in Java?

Tags: java

I'm building a Java library for a customer, and one of the things they want is a data representation of a particular set of standards they work with.  I don't want to reveal my customer's interests, but if he were an alchemist, he might want the following:

```
Elements
  Fire
    Name="Fire"
    Physical
      Temperature=451
      Color="Orange"
    Magical
      Domain="Strength"
  Water
    Name="Water"
    Physical
      Color="Blue"
  Earth
    Name="Earth"
    Magical
      Domain="Stability"
      Ordinality=1
```

I need to be able to access various data elements by name, such as:

```
  Elements.Earth.Name
  Elements.Water.Physical.Color
```

I also need to be able to iterate through attributes, as:

```
  for (MagicalType attrib : Elements.Fire.Magical)
  {
    ...
  }
```

I have actually been able to create this data structure, and I can do everything I've asked for above -- though I had to create separate arrays for the iteration, so really what I do looks more like:

```
  for (MagicalType attrib : Elements.Fire.MagicalAuxArray)
```

Unfortunately I haven't been able to meet my last requirement: the entire data structure must be immutable.  I have tried repeatedly, and scoured the web looking for examples, but so far I haven't been able to accomplish this in any reasonable manner.  Note that the final data structure will be quite large; I'm really hoping to avoid a solution that is too repetitious or creates too many public symbols.

I am a very experienced programmer, less experienced with Java.  Can anyone suggest how I might represent the above data to meet all my requirements?

Comment: +1 For the alchemy example. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 6):

A few ways that come to mind immediately:

- Don't provide setter methods for your object. You users can only create the object via a constructor and once created, it cannot be modified. This goes for other state-modification methods as well. If you want to avoid a very large parameter-list in your constructor, you can use the [Builder pattern](http://rwhansen.blogspot.com/2007/07/theres-builder-pattern-that-joshua.html) (described in *Effective Java by Joshua Bloch (2nd Ed)*)
- When returning collections, make defensive copies. In this case use a `List` instead of an array. That way you can do `return new ArrayList<MagicalType>(MagicalAuxList)` instead of `return MagicalAuxList`. This way people who use the class won't be able to modify the collection. One caveat here. If your array contains complex objects, they must be immutable as well.
- For immutable collections, you can also try using the [`unmodifiableCollection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection%28java.util.Collection%29) static method (there are similar static-methods for lists, sets, etc. - use whichever one is appropriate for you) to convert your collection when you return it. This is an alternative to defensive copying.

Comment: Thanks, these were all very useful suggestions.  Once I had a few symbol names to look up, I started find out a lot of things.  There's an article here at Stack Overflow that's related: "How to create a deep unmodifiable collection?"

Comment: @vw-register yes, that's a very good question - it should give you a lot more good ideas. In general, if you have a list of complex types you can get away with making a shallow copy of the list if the complex types are *immutable*. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Iterable` in your public API. Cleaner than Collections with all the mutators that you have to suppress. (unfortunately `Iterator` has a `remove()` method(?!) but that's just one)

```
public final Iterable<MagicalType> magics;

for(MagicalType magic : magics) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use arrays? Wouldn't immutable collections (e.g. from [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)) do a better job?

Comment: I used arrays because I wanted to be able to initialize them.  I've since discovered (as part of following up on the answers I got to this question -- thank you very much) that I can initialize a List using the Arrays.asList() to accomplish much the same thing.

As a gloss -- I was initializing the elements of the list to the values of the various physical and magical attributes.  That meant having to declare the values, and then having to enter their names a second time as elements of my list.  So now I'm using reflection, and dynamically building the lists in the constructors.

Answer (score 1):

you could try the code below that uses final, enums and unmodifiable maps. but that does not let you access by name since you need to do a get from the map. you could probably do that in groovy.

```
import java.util.*;

enum Color {
    red, green, blue;
}

class Physical {
    Physical(final Double temperature, final Color color) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.color = color;
        final Map<String, Object> map=new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("temperature", temperature);
        map.put("color", color);
        this.map=Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    final Double temperature;
    final Color color;
    final Map<String, Object> map;
}

class Magical {
    Magical(final String domain, final Integer ordinality) {
        this.domain = domain;
        this.ordinality = ordinality;
        final Map<String, Object> map=new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("domain", domain);
        map.put("ordinality", ordinality);
        this.map=Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    final String domain;
    final Integer ordinality;
    final Map<String, Object> map;
}

public enum Elements {
    earth("Earth", new Magical("Stability", 1), null), air("Air", null, null), fire("Fire", new Magical("Strength", null), new Physical(451., Color.red)), water(
            "Water", null, new Physical(null, Color.blue));
    Elements(final String name, final Magical magical, final Physical physical) {
        this.name = name;
        this.magical = magical;
        this.physical = physical;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        System.out.println(Elements.earth.name);
        System.out.println(Elements.water.physical.color);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : Elements.water.physical.map.entrySet())
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + '=' + entry.getValue());
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : Elements.earth.magical.map.entrySet())
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + '=' + entry.getValue());
    }

    final String name;
    final Magical magical;
    final Physical physical;
}
```

Comment: I did try something like this early in my experimentation.  It wasn't bad, and it gave a nice string lookup... but it wasn't what my customer specified.  I think I have it hand now, though... thank you all for your comments!